# Can PDFs contain resources that are loaded from the internet?

Tags: internet, pdf

I found [this information on the Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html#warning):

> You should be very careful when downloading documents via Tor
>   (especially DOC and PDF files) as these documents can contain Internet
>   resources that will be downloaded outside of Tor by the application
>   that opens them. This will reveal your non-Tor IP address. If you must
>   work with DOC and/or PDF files, we strongly recommend either using a
>   disconnected computer, downloading the free VirtualBox and using it
>   with a virtual machine image with networking disabled, or using Tails.
>   Under no circumstances is it safe to use BitTorrent and Tor together,
>   however.

Images can not be embedded from an external source as far as I know. So which resources are meant?

Comment: Images may not be able to be embedded, but can't PDF run scripts and those scripts access external resources?

Comment: The PDF format is incredible general, it can do all sorts of nasty things.  Whether any particular PDF reader supports them is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to your question is that can you embed JavaScipt in a PDF. And this article seems to explain that process: [“How to enhance your PDF forms with JavaScript”](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/How_to_enhance_your_PDF_forms_with_JavaScript)

So you could embed some code that connects to an external server to exchange data between the outside and your PC.

I am not sure if there are in-built security options that limit whether a pdf file can “call home.” Perhaps this also depends on the PDF reader that is being used.

EDIT:

To check the settings in Adobe Reader hit ctrl-k and select Trust manager on the left hand side. This shows the following options on my version:

[image: Adobe Trust Manager settings]

You can provide detail which websites you deem acceptable for a pdf to contact. Also, again on the left hand side, click on JavaScript, where you can turn the use of Adobe JavaScript on or off.

As per mgutt's comment below, I couldn't see why you shouldn't be able to use `app.media.getURLData()` to load external data if JavaScript, no other restrictions are set and of course the pdf application supports JavaScript.

Comment: Does anyone know a PDF that uses `app.media.getURLData()` to load media from an external source? I really like to see which of my readers support such features without my interaction.

Comment: app.media.getURLData() gets media and plays it in its appropriate viewer. This is essentially the same as embedding a link to that media in a web page. As far as I know, it is only Adobe Acrobat/Reader supporting the app.media object.

Comment: @screenshot `Internet Access from PDF Files outside the web browser` sounds like PDF Files opened through the PDF browser plugin have generally internet access?!

Answer (score 2):

You point [this out from the Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html#warning):

> …these documents can contain Internet resources that will be downloaded
>   outside of Tor by the application that opens them.

The key word in there is “can” and the warning—as I read it—is a generic “Let’s be careful out there…” statement.

I’m not 100% sure about images specifically, but exploits, tools and tutorials exist which describe methods of injecting rootkit exploits into a PDFs [such as this one](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-embed-backdoor-connection-innocent-looking-pdf-0140942/); bold emphasis is mine:

> In this exploit, we will alter an existing .pdf file that can then be
>   posted to our website. **When friends or others download it, it will
>   open a listener (a rootkit) on their system and give us total control
>   of their computer remotely.**

And more clearly stated near the end; again the bold emphasis is mine:

> Simply copy this file to your website and invite visitors to download
>   it. When our victim downloads and opens this file from your website,
>   it **will open a connection to your system that you can use to run and
>   own their computer system.**

Comment: I know about possible vulnerability in opening applications, but why is Tor warning "This will reveal your non-Tor IP address" if we are talking about rootkits?