# Can Powerpoints link to information online without user consent?

Tags: security, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, internet-security, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I recently read a superuser question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/893092/can-pdfs-contain-resources-that-are-loaded-from-the-internet) regarding whether or not PDF files could access the internet when someone opens them in Acrobat. This led me to wonder, when I open a powerpoint file, can it by default access the internet (eg loading online pictures, etc) without asking me? I have been unable to find any information on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can it by default access the internet without asking me?

It depends on the "Trust Center" settings.

---

#### Active content types in your files

> Active content is additional functionality in a file or program, such
>   as macros, add-ins, or data connections. This article lists types of
>   active content that can be blocked by settings in Trust Center and
>   which, when present in a document, cause display of message bars when
>   you open your file.
>
> If active content is blocked, a message bar appears. If more than one
>   type of active content is in the file, the message bar warns, Some
>   active content has been disabled.
>
> [image: A message bar warning about active content in a file]
>
> **Check files by using Trust Center**
>
> In Trust Center, you can configure checks of content in files for
>   computer viruses or other security hazards that can be delivered to
>   your computer by active content. These checks prevent active content
>   from running automatically, which helps to protect your computer and
>   network by preventing unexpected or malicious content from running.
>
> **To open Trust Center in an Office program**
>
> 1. Click File, and then click Options.
> 2. Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.
>
> [image]
>
> Types of active content
>
> To see the types of active content that are blocked, click Trust
>   Center Settings to open the Trust Center window.
>
> [image]
>
> Settings in Trust Center specify how Office handles active content
>
> You can also review the following list, which identifies various types
>   of active and external content that are blocked by Trust Center. A
>   message bar is displayed when the following types of active content
>   are in your files:
>
> - ActiveX controls
> - Add-ins
> - Data connections
> - Macros
> - Excel 4.0 macros
> - Spreadsheet links
>
> The following kinds of external content are linked externally to the
>   file or are embedded, and they are blocked:
>
> - Linked object linking and embedded (OLE) files
> - Color-theme files
> - Cascading style sheet (CSS) files
> - XML expansion packs
> - Links to external pictures
> - Media files
> - Real-time data servers
> - XML manifests
> - Smart documents
>
> Applies To: Access 2016, PowerPoint 2016, Excel 2016, Access 2010,
>   Visio Professional 2013, Excel 2010, Excel 2013, Word 2010, Access
>   2013, Visio 2010, Office 2010, Visio Professional 2016, Visio 2013,
>   Visio Standard 2010, PowerPoint 2010, Word 2016, PowerPoint 2013, Word
>   2013

Source [Active content types in your files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Active-content-types-in-your-files-b7ff2e8a-4055-47d4-8c7d-541e19f62bea)